# I am getting " template argument deduction/substitution failed:" Error in C++

Tags: c++, c++14, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

I have a C++ Code as Following:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Enter your code for reversed_binary_value<bool...>()
int reversed_binary_value()
{
    return 0;
}
template <bool i, bool... arg>
int reversed_binary_value()
{
    int z=0;
    z=reversed_binary_value(arg...)*2;
    if(i==0)
        return z;
    else
        return z+1;
}

template <int n, bool...digits>
struct CheckValues {
    static void check(int x, int y)
    {
        CheckValues<n-1, 0, digits...>::check(x, y);
        CheckValues<n-1, 1, digits...>::check(x, y);
    }
};

template <bool...digits>
struct CheckValues<0, digits...> {
    static void check(int x, int y)
    {
        int z = reversed_binary_value<digits...>();
        std::cout << (z+64*y==x);
    }
};

int main()
{
    int t; std::cin >> t;

    for (int i=0; i!=t; ++i) {
        int x, y;
        cin >> x >> y;
        CheckValues<6>::check(x, y);
        cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

I am getting "no matching function for call to ‘reversed_binary_value(bool, bool, bool, bool, bool)" and then "template argument deduction/substitution failed:"
This code is for the question on https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/cpp-variadics/problem so I can not change the locked code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error in your code is calling `reversed_binary_value()`

```
z=reversed_binary_value(arg...)*2;
```

that expect the boolean values a **template** parameters.

So you have to call it as follows

```
z=reversed_binary_value<arg...>()*2;
// ....................^......^^^
```

But now you have another problem: when the variadic pack `args...` is empty, the call become

```
z=reversed_binary_value<>()*2;
```

So you explicitly call a template function (the `<>`), without template arguments, when your terminal `reverse_binary_value()` function

```
int reversed_binary_value()
{
    return 0;
}
```

isn't a template one.

I suggest you a dirty but useful trick: transform the terminal version in a template function that a accept something different from a value (maybe a type) and  with a default argument; by example

```
template <typename = void>
int reversed_binary_value()
{
    return 0;
}
```

This way the final empty list call

```
z=reversed_binary_value<>()*2;
```

matches `reverse_binary_value<void>()`.

Answer (score 2):

Another option to @max66's answer is to use `enable_if` to disable the recursive version for the special one-parameter case. This allows to unambiguously overload the function  with another template:

```
template<bool b>
int reversed_binary_value()
{
    return b?1:0;
}

template <bool i=1, bool... arg>
std::enable_if_t<sizeof...(arg) != 0,int>
reversed_binary_value()
{
    int z=0;
    z=reversed_binary_value<arg...>()*2;
    if(i==0)
        return z;
    else
        return z+1;
}
```

If you want to be fancy(horrible?) with C++17 fold expressions,  here is  three-line solution:

```cpp
template<bool...Args>
constexpr int reversed_binary_value(){
    int res=0,tmp=0;
    (tmp|=...|=((res*=2)+=Args));
    return res;
}

int main()
{
    static_assert(reversed_binary_value<1,1,1,1>()==15);
    static_assert(reversed_binary_value<0,1,0,1>()==10);
    static_assert(reversed_binary_value<1,0,0,1>()==9);
}
```

Comment: Very nice the fold expression solution.